# _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null for Apple Login

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid, microsoft-identity-platform, apple-login

I have setup "Login with Apple" in my .Net Core Razor Pages app (.Net 5) which is using Microsoft Identity Framework for user management.

I followed [this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Implementing-Sign-In-with-Apple-in-ASPNET-Core) tutorial of Scott which helped me as far as the Apple Login page.

But after the successful login when the Call-Back endpoint is called, I am getting `null` in the `_signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` method call.

**My initial research suggested that the ID Token may not contain required data.
Which is correct because the ID Token returned by the Apple does not contain `email` or `name` even though it is requested in the `scope`.**

Sample request:`https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?client_id=net.demo.client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdemo.website.net%2Fsignin-apple&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=email%20name&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637679-omitted`

Here's the Authentication setup called from `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method:

```
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            //options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "cookie";//Commented because this line was causing the Google login stop.
            //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "apple";//Commented because this line was causing the Google login stop.
        })
               .AddCookie("cookie")
               .AddOpenIdConnect("apple", "Apple", async options =>
               {
                   options.Authority = "https://appleid.apple.com"; // disco doc: https://appleid.apple.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

                   options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                   options.SignInScheme = "cookie";

                   options.DisableTelemetry = true;

                   options.Scope.Clear(); // otherwise I had consent request issues
                   options.Scope.Add("email");
                   options.Scope.Add("name");
                   options.ClientId = "net.demo.client"; // Service ID
                   options.CallbackPath = "/signin-apple"; // corresponding to your redirect URI

                   options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                      {
                          context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientSecret = TokenGenerator.CreateNewToken();
                          return Task.CompletedTask;
                      };
                   options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                   {
                       var builder = new UriBuilder(context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);
                       builder.Scheme = "https";
                       builder.Port = -1;
                       context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = builder.ToString();
                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   };
                   options.UsePkce = false; // apple does not currently support PKCE (April 2021)
               })
           ;
```

Here's the call-back endpoint:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
            return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();//Returns null.
        if (info == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information.";
            return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
    //Code omitted...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is ASP.Net Identity configured to use the "cookie" scheme for external logins?

By default it will use `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme`. Try using:

```
options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
```

instead of

```
options.SignInScheme = "cookie";
```